# Using npm with sudo return: "NPM is not known..." bug

Tags: node.js, npm, sudo

When i am using `sudo npm` it returns the

```
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.4.5
```

while running without `sudo` is fine.

More confusing is that my `node -v` is `v9.8.0` but `nodejs -v` is `v0.10` .None of them is `v4.4.5`

How can I resolve this.

Comment: You've installed npm once with sudo, once without. Now you've two versions hanging around, one doesn't work with the node version you non sudo version is using. Unsinstall npm and node, and install it again properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have 2 version of npm installed you need to remove them all and install a fresh version of npm

```
sudo npm uninstall npm -g
```

try also to remove everything related to npm

```
rm -rf /usr/local/{lib/node{,/.npm,_modules},bin,share/man}/npm*
```

and then re install a fresh version of npm

Comment: I cannot run sudo npm uninstall npm -g because of the same problem

Comment: then remove it with rm -rf